# wget in msys failed to download target file behind HTTP redirect

Tags: wget, msys

I am using `wget` in **msys** to download a target file behind a HTTP redirect, but it always saved a file named by the HTTP redirect directly instead of the target file behind the redirect. After Google, there is an option `--trust-server-names=on` that can solve the problem. But for `wget` of **msys** version, it doesn't have this option at all. Therefore, does it mean:

-> for `wget` of **msys** version(I mean the version from MinGW site), no way to solve the mentioned problem.

-> To solve the problem in msys, I must download src files and compile it in msys and add the option `--trust-server-names=on` by myself.

Any other methods I miss?

Answer (score 0):

For the wget without the option **--trust-server-names=on**, the option `--spider` might help . Using the option "--spider", it can retrieve the HTTP redirect and tell you the real location. I tried it on some address. Some worked (then you can use wget to download via the real location) and the other failed. For the failing address, the output is like this, e.g., :

```
Length: 2175717 (2.1M) [application/x-download]
Remote file exists but does not contain any link -- not retrieving.
```

It seemed that it found a file but couldn't find a link. In this case, I don't know how to go on.